# Changing the font format

Tags: css, fonts, format

I saw in a video tutorial that for changing font format, she changes the font extension!

***This means that:***

1- We have a font.ttf

2. copy of it and change the extension, font.ttf ---> font.eot
3. copy of it again and change the extension, font.ttf ---> font.woff

***So:***

1- It is appropriate?

2. The **main question**: Does the browser detects that font.eot and font.woff?

Thank You!

Comment: As long as you've linked the font correctly in your css nothing else should matter?

Comment: Just copying a file and then changing the extension will not work. (In this particular case, it means that only the original ttf file will work properly and that only browsers which can use ttf will display the font.) HOWEVER, loading a file into an appropriate editor and then doing "Save As...", and changing the extension, will also change the format of the written file. So, the answer is, it depends on what the video is actually showing.

Answer (score 0):

## Overview

What you are following is called **embedding fonts**. I would like to see your code in which you are referencing your fonts but the answer is **yes**.

## How it works

The user browser will see the font you choose as long as your reference the actual font files on your server (folder structure). You can just name the font, you will also have to tell the CSS where the file is in your folder structure and ensure this is uploaded to the server when your deploying the website/app.

## Testing

On your computer you may have a font x, if on your computer this is installed you will see it work even though your code might not right. I recommend that for testing purposed you rename your font in your site to something unique, and use a fallback font. This way if the code works it will load the proper font, if not you will fall back! to the defined font.

## Warning

If you don't rename your main font but it is installed on your computer it will then still work.

## Hint:

It is good practice to try and use web fonts where possible, have a look at google webfonts.